# p4python check if any actions are being run

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

I have a threaded timer running to disconnect from p4 after a certain amount of time (because perforce will auto timeout in our application and fails to reconnect).  I want to make sure that I do not disconnect if any long action is running (like downloading a large file).  Are there any p4 commands that can check if there are currently commands being run.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can run `p4 monitor show` to check from the server side if any commands are running.

For your use case, though, it would be more straightforward for your script to simply keep track of its own `run()` calls, since anything you care about will take place in the context of one of those calls.  It's generally good practice to close your connection once you're done invoking commands with `run()`, since holding idle connections open can potentially DDoS the server if enough client instances do it.